# Can't install Silex webprofiler

Tags: php, namespaces, profiler, silex, provider

I work on a Silex project, but I can not install the webprofiler.
I followed the official installation of the web profiler for Silex (https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler) but this returns a 500 error.

My code :

```
//I do not use "MonologServiceProvider".
use Silex\Provider;
//Twig provider is already register.
$app->register(new Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
// I have no error here.


//But if i add this, this returns a 500 error.
$app->register(new Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
    'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../cache/profiler',
    'profiler.mount_prefix' => '/_profiler', // this is the default
));

$app->run();
```

This is my arborescence:

[image: Image of arborescence]

The bundle webprofiler is in the `vendor / silex / web-profiler` directory which has the namespace '`Silex \ Provider`'.
But there is also a "`Silex \ Provider`" namespace in the `Silex / silex` folder. So I was wondering if he was not going to look into the wrong folder.

This just returns a 500 error ..

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: What's the error message? Did you check your logs?

Comment: Hi, I added that for errors.


`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler;`



`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ExceptionHandler;`



`// set the error handling`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(-1);`


Now I can see the error that appears:

http://imgur.com/a/XmV2E


The error was too long to fit in the comment, sorry.

Comment: It's good ! 
I found my error, I did not use the boot () function in the right place. Here is the image of my code for those who would have the same problem.
http://imgur.com/a/tAMvi
Thanks !